# Vim cannot create directory to store info about folds

Tags: macos, vim

I am on Mac OS X El Capitan. It seems I save write folds in Vim using the command "mkview", as it complains about

```
E739: Cannot create directory: /Users/Blah/.vim/view      
E190: Cannot open "/Users/Blah/.vim/view/~=+Box Sync=+ExSL-Alpha=" for writing
```

Comment: Do you have the necessary rights?

Comment: I am a little noob in "rights" thing. I do have the sudo access.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that `mkview` can't create the subfolder because the "main" `.vim` folder doesn't exist.
If you create the `~/.vim` folder manually, it should work:

```
mkdir ~/.vim
```

Comment: Worked like a charm!